# tensorflow working on the anaconda prompt but not on the command prompt

Tags: tensorflow, installation, anaconda

[image: Example]

I've just installed tensorflow in my machine and I decided to install it with anaconda. It works just fine there but when I try to run it with the command prompt it acts as if it didn't exist. 
I am getting a hard time getting tensorflow to work

Answer (score 0):

From the anaconda window you activated your `env`, `base` in your case.
When you open command prompt you have to activate that `env`

`activate base`

then run `python`

Comment: Doesn't seem to fix it, now it shows (base). I'm afraid I don't know much about anaconda and environments...

Comment: try creating an env and do `conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Comment: You can add the python path in control panel environment variable and try importing tensorflow from command prompt